# Not able to open phpmyadmin in ubuntu (ec2 server)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have followed amazon tutorial to install `Apache2`, `mysql` and `php` on ubuntu Ec2 and when tried to access `phpmyadmin` its not working.

Initially some other process was using port :80 so i was not able restart apache and then i have changed `Listen:80` to `Listen 8080` . Now apache working fine, but still no hope on `phpmyadmin`

Pls check attached screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What does your Security group attached to the ec2 instance include?

Comment: ??? i didnt understand